# Mybatis @Insert Error: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis

```
org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'testStr' in 'class Test.TestModel'.
```

the error occured in the following methods:

```
public interface TestMapper {
    @Insert({"INSERT INTO PLUProps.Test VALUES(#{id}, #{testStr})"})
    int insertData(TestModel testModel);
}

//Test
private int insertData(){
    TestModel testModel = new TestModel();
    testModel.setId(1);
    testModel.setTestSTr("123123");
    return testMapper.insertData(testModel);
}
```

In the entity class of TestModel, I used @Data annotation from lombok to automatically generate setter and getter methods.

```
@Data
public class TestModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1180681799256416275L;
    private int id;
    private String testSTr;
}
```

Is the error caused by the wrong @Insert statement I wrote? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Typo here.**

Error complains about getters and setters so

Change `private String testSTr;` to `private String testStr;` and create getters and setters accordingly.

OR

change `#{testStr})` to `#{testSTr})`

Comment: oh...my mistake...Thank you.

Comment: happy coding...:)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo either in the query or in the field.

The field is named `testSTr` (note the capitable `T`) so the statement should be

```
INSERT INTO PLUProps.Test VALUES(#{id}, #{testSTr})
```

Alternatively change the field name to `testStr`.